# Extract variables from pattern matching

Tags: regex, vb.net, match, extract

I'm not a match-pattern expert and I've been working on this for a few hours with no chance :/

I have an input string just like this:

```
Dim text As String = "32 Barcelona {GM C} 2 {*** Some ""cool"" text here}"
```

And I just want to extract 3 things:

1. Barcelona
2. GM C
3. *** Some "cool" text here

The pattern I'm trying is something like this:

```
Dim pattern As String = "^32\s(?<city>[^]].*\s)\{(?<titles>.*\})*"

Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(text, pattern)

If (m.Success) Then

    Dim group1 As Group = m.Groups.Item("city")
    Dim group2 As Group = m.Groups.Item("titles")

    If group1.Success Then
        MsgBox("City:" + group1.Value + ":", MsgBoxStyle.Information)   
    End If

    If group2.Success Then
        MsgBox(group2.Value, MsgBoxStyle.Information)  
    End If
    Else
        MsgBox("fail")
    End If
```

But it's not working anyway :(
What should the pattern be to extract these 3 variables ?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the "Cool" text? If not, RegEx may not be the best choice, as your input doesn't meet the formal definition for "regular" input.

Comment: On second thought, you can probably still do it, because you can take everything up to the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^\d*(?<City>[A-Z a-z0-9]*)\s*\{(?<Titles>[A-Z a-z0-9]*)\}.*?\{(?<Cool>.*?)\}$`

Seems to match your sample input.

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/) is a great tool for designing regular expressions.

Comment: Worked almost great. Thought me the way how to use it. I guess the pattern "^\d*\s(?<City>.*?)\s\{(?<Titles>.*)\}.*?\{(?<Text>.*?)\}$" is more proper for my situation.